# How to know which is the default mail client?

Tags: delphi, outlook, delphi-xe2

When my application starts, I want to know if Outlook is installed and whether it is the default mail client.

For installation i just check a registry key, but how to know if it is the default mail client?

Answer (score 6):

According to this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203067%28VS.85%29.aspx) "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail can contain zero or more subkeys, one for each registered email application".

Regarding which of the registered e-mail apps is the default one, the same link says that:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\(default)
```

will give you the default mail app for the current user (if it is set), while

```
HKEY_LOCAL_SOFTWARE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\(default)
```

gives you the system-wide one.

The link also states also that it is not the same having the mail client registered as Start menu mail application, as the system default email client or the registered *mailto* handler (which seems a bit odd imho).

The information in that link applies to XP, Vista and Win 7.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

The installed e-mail clients are listed under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail
```

The default string value of this key holds the currently selected default mail client, in our case `Microsoft Outlook`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried to set WIndows LIve Mail as default program by using http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ZA/windows-vista/Change-the-default-e-mail-program but i sill read "Microsoft Outlook" in that Registry key...

Comment: I'm not sure but there may also be an `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail` that overrides

Answer (score 2):

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open